# How can i make a GROUP BY with a variable CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a join on 2 tables (a and l) (1 to many relationship)
Sometimes l exists sometimes not
Both tables has a Date. When l exists i need to filter on l.Date otherwyse i filter on a.Date
My problem is how to group by MONTH(a.Date) when l.Date is null or MONTH(l.Date) case is not null

I am getting this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

My Query:

```
SELECT month,  
(SELECT COUNT(numero)   
FROM WR_AtivTecnicas a   
FULL OUTER JOIN WR_AtivTecnicasLinhas l ON l.NumeroAtiv = a.Numero   
WHERE ( (YEAR(l.Data) = null AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (MONTH(l.Data) = null AND MONTH(a.Data) = month) OR  MONTH(a.Data) = month)  
GROUP BY  
 CASE WHEN MONTH(l.Data) = null THEN MONTH(a.Data)  
 ELSE MONTH(l.DATA)  
 END)  
FROM(VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12))[1 to 12](month)
```

For example WR_AtivTecnicas can be:

```
Numero | Data    
-------|------------    
1      | 2019-01-01  
2      | 2019-02-01  
3      | 2019-02-10
```

And WR_AtivTecnicaLinhas:

```
NumeroAtiv | Line | Data  
-----------|-------------    
1          |   1  | 2019-01-10  
1          |   2  | 2019-01-11  
3          |   1  | 2019-02-12  
3          |   2  | 2019-02-12  
3          |   3  | 2019-03-01
```

Desired Result for above example:

```
Month|Count    
-----|-----    
1    | 2    
2    | 3   
3    | 1    
...    
12   | 0
```

month = 1 to 12

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `CASE` and everything do do with your subquery. What about it don't you understand, as it's quite clear on what the error is. Also, it's a really bad idea to use clauses like `YEAR(l.Data) = null` and `YEAR(a.Data) = '2019'` in your `WHERE`. Use **proper** date logic. For example `WHERE YourDate >= '20190101' AND YourDate < '20200101'`

Comment: As i said, sometimes l does not exist so the l.Data is null, in that case i need to compare with a.Data

Comment: *"sometimes l does not exist so the l.Data is null"* That isn't an excuse for poor date logic in your `WHERE`.

Comment: Have you tried `COALESCE(l.DATA, a.Data)`?

Comment: Also, ***nothing*** equals `NULL`, including `NULL`. `(YEAR(l.Data) = null` will **never** be true. When comparing against `NULL` values, you **must** use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. There is a lot to fix in the `WHERE` of this query. (For the specific clause I highlight, there is no need to use `YEAR()` at all. If `YEAR(l.Data)` has a value of `NULL` then `l.Data` must do.)

Comment: OK Larnu, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: i Changed to this:
    SELECT mes,
    (SELECT COUNT(numero) 
    FROM WR_AtivTecnicas a 
    FULL OUTER JOIN WR_AtivTecnicasLinhas l ON l.NumeroAtiv = a.Numero 
    WHERE ( (l.Data IS NULL AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (l.Data IS NULL AND MONTH(a.Data) = mes) OR  MONTH(a.Data) = mes)
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN l.Data IS NULL THEN MONTH(a.Data) ELSE MONTH(l.DATA) END)
    FROM(VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12))[1 to 12](mes)

But getting same error

Comment: JoeFletch,

I tried:

SELECT mes,
(SELECT COUNT(numero) 
FROM WR_AtivTecnicas a 
FULL OUTER JOIN WR_AtivTecnicasLinhas l ON l.NumeroAtiv = a.Numero 
WHERE ( (l.Data IS NULL AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (l.Data IS NULL AND MONTH(a.Data) = mes) OR  MONTH(a.Data) = mes)
GROUP BY COALESCE(l.DATA, a.Data))
FROM(VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12))[1 to 12](mes)

but same error

Comment: Thank you guys, after all my query works. I found the error here:

WHERE ( (YEAR(l.Data) = null AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (MONTH(l.Data) = null AND MONTH(a.Data) = month) OR  MONTH(a.Data) = month)  
The correct is:
WHERE ( (YEAR(l.Data) = null AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (MONTH(l.Data) = null AND MONTH(a.Data) = month) OR  MONTH(l.Data) = month)  

I put "a.Data" instead "l.Data" at the end

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, after all my query works(Changing the "=nulls" to "IS NULL" Thanks Larnu)
I found the error here:

```
WHERE ( (YEAR(l.Data) = null AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (MONTH(l.Data) = null AND MONTH(a.Data) = month) OR  MONTH(a.Data) = month)
```

The correct is:

```
WHERE ( (YEAR(l.Data) = null AND YEAR(a.Data) = '2019') OR YEAR(l.Data) = '2019') AND ( (MONTH(l.Data) = null AND MONTH(a.Data) = month) OR  MONTH(l.Data) = month)
```

I put "a.Data" instead "l.Data" at the end. Sorry for your time.